# How to set sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail Template seperate for when groip id 4 using module

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

> How to send separate Email template
> (customer_password_forgot_email_template) when
>
> user Group id=4 using
> module **extend Mage_Customer_Model_Customer**.

```
class Creative_Login_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
{
    public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
    {
        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
        }

        $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

> This code working but i want separate mail template for only groupid=
> 4.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Answer Click Hear](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/36282/6317)

ravi.As `you reweite customer class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`  and then  $t`his  give customer object`

in this function  you can get customer if by using below code :

```
  $this->getGroupId()
```

**also you need create an customer forgort pasword rest password email html template and define it config.xml**

**Step1:**  add new customer `forgot password confirmation mail template`  for `this customer group` using

```
below code at config.xml



<template>
        <email>
            <customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew translate="label" module="customer">
                <label>Forgot Password</label>
                <file>account_password_reset_confirmation_new.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew>
        </email>
    </template>
```

by this code i have add  **new email template** and **template code** is `customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew`

**Step2:** for getting this email template add below code  at outside  in config.xml

```
<default>
    <customer>
      <password>
                <forgot_email_template_newgroup>customer_password_forgot_email_template_groupnew</forgot_email_template_newgroup>
      </password>
    </customer>
</default>
```

**Step3:** you need to call this template `at  sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail` of rewrite function

```
if($this->getGroupId()==4) <!-- check your group id -->
     $this->_sendEmailTemplate('customer/password/forgot_email_template_newgroup', self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
      }
      else{
         $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
      }
```

**Step4:** `you to create new html name as account_password_reset_confirmation_new.html at app/locale/yourlanguage/template/email`